# WebRTC NTP Server

Tags: webrtc, ntp

WebRTC has an experimental statistic `googCaptureStartNtpTimeMs` in the ssrc recv report of WebRTC stats. I believe it is defined as the NTP time when the stream started on the sender's side in milliseconds.

I'm want to sync my clients with the same NTP clock WebRTC uses to generate that `googCaptureStartNtpTimeMs`.

I've been googling around and searching/reading WebRTC source and I cannot find which NTP server(s) are used to generate this stat. I'm assuming all NTP servers cannot possibly be in sync, so I need to figure out exactly which NTP server WebRTC is using so I can sync my clients with their `googCaptureStartNtpTimeMs` timestamp.

I see a few options:

- `pool.ntp.org`
- `time.google.com`
- `time1.google.com`
- `ntp.google.com`

Searching for these in the WebRTC source yields no results. `pool.ntp.org` seems promising because it will help find an NTP server close (low latency) to  where the request was made from. But, if the NTP pool is not in sync with NTP WebRTC, it will be useless to me unless I can get the offset between NTP pool and NTP WebRTC.

My question boils down to:

- Are all NTP servers standardized and in sync with each other?
- If not, which NTP server(s) does WebRTC use to generate `googCaptureStartNtpTimeMs`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`googCaptureStartNtpTimeMs` has nothing to do with NTP servers. It's in the local clock. "Ntp" in the name comes from the format in which time is passed in RTCP SenderReport packets, and doesn't imply that some NTP server synchronization is going on.

Your understanding of the metric definition is a little off.
It's a **local (receiver's)** time when the track started sending.

The clock synchronization is done internally by WebRTC using RTT estimate and RTCP SenderReport packets. Note, to have RTT estimate, the peer has to be sending something, and it takes some time (up to 20 seconds for audio tracks, based on RTCP SR sending period). Before all the estimates are available, the metric will report -1.